# My popup resizes in the sidebar when scrolling

Tags: wordpress, popup

I use WordPress and in my theme I have a page with a sidebar. I modified it and added a button that opens a popup but when I scroll down, the popup goes into the sidebar like this:

[image: img 1]

And that's the code:

[image: Code]

The theme uses `theiastickysidebar`.

Comment: Where is popup in html?
Is it position:fixed?

Comment: It is in the file where the sidebar is located because the button that opens it must be located here. Yes, it is in fixed

Comment: Move popup somewhere before closing body tag.

Comment: This is a php file that does not have a body tag

Comment: So mode the popup html code to another file